# What is the best way of displaying conditional content in ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I am using this a lot and I feel like I'm doing it wrong.

in ng-repeat, I want to show some part, if the condition is right but I don't want it to be in loop, I need to display it when I want and where I want.

for example:
$scope.selectedItemId is defined and changed from javascript dynamically.

```
<div ng-repeat=“item in items”>
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
    <div ng-if=“selectedItemId==item.id”>{{item.condition}}</div>
</div>
```

At the example, instead of item.condition, it may be a rest result or a directive too.

It looks like it checks for every item in the loop. I want to put the content to there dynamically. When user clicks a button which sets the selected item, I want it to show the content of it where ng-if is now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the loop. For example, your html:

```
<button ng-click="setItem('uniq-id')">click me</button>
<div>{{selectedItem.condition}}</div>
```

And js (I'm use lodash for simplification):

```
$scope.setItem = function (id) {
    $scope.selectedItem = _.find($scope.items, {id: id});
};
```